# MySQL ODBC driver source code

Tags: mysql, odbc

Is the MySQL ODBC source code available online somewhere? I can only find the binaries on the official MySQL web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it now at https://code.launchpad.net/~myodbc-developers/myodbc/3.51 for future reference.

Comment: I can't able open above location.

Comment: Thanks for responce @Inge Henriksen

Answer (score 0):

It's right there: Downloads-> MySQL Connectors-> Connector/ODBC

Once in the download page, select "Source code" in the "Select platform" drop down list.